# How to flip two views in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, flip

I want to flip front view with back view and again flip back view to front view in tableviewcell position and size of both views are same in tableViewcell. I want to perform this animation after 2 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
let main = UIView() // cell view name 
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = "flip"
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
main.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
```

Comment: i have 2 views for fliping ,how to achieve?

Comment: i dont want to flip cell ,i want to flip view inside cell,not working.